# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I followed CodeLyon's tutorial on YouTube to make a discord music bot because I have no idea what I'm doing, and I don't know what I've done wrong or what to do. The bot joins the voice channel I'm in, but it doesn't play anything, and this comes up in the terminal:

```
var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var key;for(key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}Module["arguments"]=[];Module["thisProgram"]="./this.program";Module["quit"]=function(status,toThrow){throw toThrow};Module["preRun"]=[];Module["postRun"]=[];var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof process.versions==="object"&&typeof process.versions.node==="string";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var scriptDirectory="";function locateFile(path){if(Mod   
abort(TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

const token = '';

const PREFIX = '!';

var servers = {};

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!')
})

bot.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'play':

            function play(connection, message){
                 var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                 server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                 server.queue.shift();

                 server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                     if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);
                    }else {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                });
            }


             if(!args[1]){
                 message.channel.send("You need to enter a link.");
                 return;
             }

             if(!message.member.voiceChannel){
                 message.channel.send("You have to be in a voice channel.");
                 return;
             }

             if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                 queue: []
             }

             var server = servers[message.guild.id];

             server.queue.push(args[1]);

             if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
                 play(connection, message);
             })
             break;

    }


});

bot.login(token);
```

(I've removed the value for token)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3375

If you are using ffmpeg-binaries, uninstall it and try ffmpeg-static or a regular FFmpeg installation instead.

Otherwise I suggest to open an issue at the prism-media repository.